# Multiple foreach to process nested arrays -- PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, nested

I would first like to thank you for taking the time to look at my question--I am quite novice at PHP/CodeIgniter programming, however, I enjoy it very much.

What I am trying to do:

1) Retrieve each CompanyId associated with the company when the user is logged in. I achieve this by passing the $CompanyId (in my controller) from the session as a parameter to a query in my model. I have this working well as such:

```
 // Assign query result to array  to be used in view
    $data['campaigns'] = $this->model_record->retrieve_campaign($CompanyId);
```

2) The return value is an array nested as such:

```
Array ( 
[campaigns] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [CampaignId] => 1 
        [DID] => 2394434444 
        [FWDDID] => 3214822821 
        [ProductId] => 1 
        [CampaignName] => Fort Myers Bus #1 
        [ProductName] => CallTrack - Sharktek 
        [Active] => 1 
        [CompanyId] => 1 ) 
    )
```

3) Once this is processed, I am trying to create a for each loop that queries each CampaignId through another query in my model. Due to the MVC pattern I am implementing, I have to pass the results of this query to my $data array to send to the view.

```
foreach($data['campaigns'] as $campaign) {
    $ids[] = $campaign['CampaignId'];
}

foreach ($ids as $row) {
    $data['ids'] = $this->model_record->week_data(0,$row, $StartDate);
}
```

4) I am then trying to test view all the results of my queries in my view, however, I am only receiving one value, but when I echo the results of the foreach of the CampaignIds, it they all show up. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
<?php 
foreach($ids as $row):
echo $ids['MyCount'];
endforeach
 ?>
```

5 Extra) I have not begun to approach this yet, but once I get this working, I would like to run the query week_data 7 times as it is returning the data for each day of the week. My assumption is that I would place a for loop until it hits 7, is this correct?

Thank you again, for attempting to help me--I greatly appreciate the work many of you put into this community.

Comment: About the 5 Extra your assumption is a wrong one, you can do it in one query using LIMIT and OFFSET sql constructs, in active record its $this->db->limit($offset,$limit);

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$data['ids'] = $this->model_record->week_data(0,$row, $StartDate);
```

Should look like:

```
$data['ids'][] = $this->model_record->week_data(0,$row, $StartDate);
```

As it is, the first line overwrites `$data['ids']` until all you're left with is the last one. You need to add them to an array to collect all of them.

Comment: You have just saved me hours of staring at tutorials. Thanks mate!
To process the query seven times, would you suggest a for loop?